# Moving element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 5 button like this:

```
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
```

When someone cliked on one of this button,that button be in the middle and the order do not chnage(about order, i mean order of 1 2 3 4 5 be  consecutive,all of position will be change but the order will not change),for example i click on number 1 and it will be like this:

```
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
```

or button number 2:

```
        <button>5</button>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
```

I dont have no idea what to do with javascript or jquery
help me plz.
Thanks

Comment: but why `button 2 ` & `button 3` is changing their position

Comment: one could use http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: about order, i mean order of 1 2 3 4 5 be  consecutive

Comment: Provide a live example and show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function rotate(n) {
  var body = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var pos =  (n + i + 2) % 5 + 1;
   body += "<button onclick=rotate("+pos+")>"+pos+"</button>";
  }
  $(".buttons").html(body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick=rotate(1)>1</button>
  <button onclick=rotate(2)>2</button>
  <button onclick=rotate(3)>3</button>
  <button onclick=rotate(4)>4</button>
  <button onclick=rotate(5)>5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  //give each button its order (10,20,30,40,50)
  $('button').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('order', (i + 1) * 10);
  });

  //if the clicked button is after the middle button, then insert it before current middle
  // if it is before the middle button, make it appear after current middle
  $(this).attr('order', ($(this).attr('order') < 30) ? 35 : 25);


  //sort the buttons according to the new order..
  var buttons = $('button').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).attr('order') - $(b).attr('order')
  });


  //append them back to their parent.
  parent.append(buttons);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>
```